# Repeat a JavaScript result that is being displayed with <span id="x"></span> again on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

The scenario, I have several JavaScript calculations (based on user input) on my page. The results of which are displayed via `<span id="x"></span>` for example..

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = +(Math.round(document.form.input.value /25.4 + "e+2")  + "e-2");
```

My question is how best to display the result if I want to use it again later in the same page.

I have tried just using `<span id="x"></span>` again later in the page but because the "id" is the same this doesn't work so my current workaround is just to simply repeat the JavaScript calc again and then call it again with "2" on the end like so..

```
<span id="x2"></span>

document.getElementById("x2").innerHTML = +(Math.round(document.form.input.value /25.4 + "e+2")  + "e-2");
```

but this has resulted in a lot of repeated/unnecessary extra calculations and I can't help but think there must be a simpler way to repeat the result later on in the same page?

Comment: make it into a function and pass the id in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use innerHTML with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489716/how-to-use-innerhtml-with-class)

Comment: @mark_b I really don't like the accepted answer of that question

Comment: @CristianTraìna Then add an answer you do like... and downvote the accepted answer.

Comment: you can try document.getElementByClassName("x").innerHTML

Comment: @AmitSharma Read the answers to [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/215552). There is no `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: @AmitSharma You can't do that. It returns an array like object on which you would have to iterate to get the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

create unique IDs in different span elements, create a function and the pass the IDs.

```
function fun(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = +(Math.round(document.form.input.value /25.4 + "e+2") + "e-2");
}
```

Comment: looks, good, how do i pass the ids please?
Like <span id="fun(2)"></span> ?

Answer (score 0):

then anywhere you want to trigger the function, use func(x2)